# Populate Partial View with data depending on which link is clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Say I have these lists:

```
   <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" })</li>
   <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Recs", "Recs", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }) </li>
```

I could chose to create a Partial View belonging to each list/Action. But if there are many lists, I will equally have many Partial Views. I want to only have one Partial View, and depending on which list/link is clicked, fill the Partial View with the right html, data or what ever, belonging to that list, and then return the partial view. How can I do this?

My action methods look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_RefreshedHandler");
        }

        return View();
    }

   public ActionResult Recs()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_RefreshedHandler");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

As you can see, they both return the same partial view, but the content of that partial view will depend on wich link the user clicked.

So far the partial view is as boring as this:

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.PageRefreshModel

<div id="retrievedContentDiv" style="height: 500px; width: 700px; margin-top: 50px; 
     margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <h2> Partial view</h2>
    <p>Content should be inserted according to the link that called the partial view</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the content you want to display is based on the `PageRefreshModel` properties, then each method should initialize the model and set the value of its properties, then pass it to the partial i.e. `return PartialView("_RefreshedHandler", yourModel);`

Comment: But each view that belongs to the Action method above will contain some markup, and the Partial view should in some way know that it should insert the markup that is in the view that called it. I'm very new to MVC, so I apologize if I ask dumb questions. I just don't know what to google for to get some examples on this?

Comment: Its a little unclear exactly what your wanting to do. Your partial declares model `PageRefreshModel` but you not passing the model to the partial in your methods. If you want to display something extra that not part of the model, you can use `ViewBag` - e.g. in the method, `ViewBag.Content = "Some Content";` and in the view `<p>@ViewBag.Content</p>`. Otherwise you should have different views to display different content.